# How many Hamiltonian cycles are there in a complete graph that must contain certain edges?

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

Consider a complete graph $G$ that has $n \geq 4$ vertices.

Each vertex in this graph is indexed $[n]=\{1,2,3, \dots n\}$

In this context, a Hamiltonian cycle is defined **solely** by the **collection of edges** it contains. We don't need to consider the cycle's orientation or starting point.

Question: How many Hamiltonian cycles in graph $G$ contain both the edges $\{1,2\}$ and $\{3,4\}$?

---

For the sake of this exercise, let's pretend we have a **complete graph** made of 5 vertices.

Index: $[n] = {1,2,3,4,5}$

[image]

Since the graph must contain edges $\{1,2\}$ and $\{3,4\}$, I treat them as individual vertices. Which means I only have three vertices:

$\{1,2\}, \{3,4\}, 5$

If I'm correct, this graph should have 4 Hamiltonian cycles. However, I can't get this number no matter how I try.

- $3! = 6$ (Wrong)
- $3!/2n = 1$ (Wrong)

I've been told that the edges $\{1,2\}$ and $\{3,4\}$ are directional but I'm not sure how to account for this level of complexity.

Comment: Clearly it depends on *which* edges must be included.  As such, there is no generic universal answer to your question.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Actually, I think you can do slightly better. It should be possible to determine the answer based only on the *number* of disjoint paths formed by the fixed edges. Since the question explicitly fixes edges $\{1,2\}$ and $\{3,4\}$ it is indeed well-posed.

Comment: Imagine $n$ is large and you choose your $n$ edges that themselves form a Hamiltonian path.  Then the number of such paths is $1$.  Suppose instead that you choose $n$ "random" edges.  Clearly there will be more than one Hamiltonian paths through that set.  So which answer is "right"?

Comment: @platty I think so too. Since it is a complete graph it shouldn't matter which vertex gets which index. All we know is that {1,2} and {3,4} are edges that don't share the same vertex.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork That's not relevant to the question asked though, which is "Question: How many Hamiltonian cycles can there be if the graph must contain the edges $\{1,2\}$ and $\{3,4\}$?"

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I edited the question just now. It's the same thing but I hope the wording is clearer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question can be interpreted as asking how many ways there are to construct a Hamiltonian cycle under these constraints. Since we know $\{1,2\}$ must be in the cycle, it seems reasonable to assume that we start at vertex $1$ and the first edge traversed is $\{1,2\}$. From here, the rest of the cycle is given by a permutation of the remaining vertices $\{3,4, \dots, n\}$ under the constraint that 3 and 4 have to be consecutive. Similar to your idea of treating $\{3,4\}$ as a single vertex, we can permute these $n-3$ objects ($n$ vertices, minus the two we already used and treating 3 and 4 as a single unit) in $(n-3)!$ ways. Then there are 2 orientations for the $\{3,4\}$ edge, so we multiply to get a total of $2(n-3)!$ Hamiltonian cycles.

In your example, we do indeed get $2(5-3)! = 4$ such Hamiltonian cycles.

As a side note, you can generalize this result. If the $k$ "fixed edges" comprise $p$ vertex-disjoint paths, then the number of Hamiltonian cycles should be $2^{p-1}(n-k-1)!$. There's $p-1$ paths to orient, $n - k - p$ vertices which are still on their own, and $p-1$ paths to place as a single unit somewhere in the permutation (so we permute $n-k-1$ objects in this step).